# Monitor TCP connection using half-open/embryonic connection

Tags: java, networking, tcp, netty

I would like to monitor a TCP/IP endpoint using TCP [half-open](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) or [embryonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Embryonic_connection) connection as defined in [RFC793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793). The purpose of such monitoring is to detect whether the TCP endpoint is available or not. Hal-open monitoring is important to reduce the footprint of such monitoring for the TCP endpoint.
The TCP cinematic is `SYN->SYN-ACK<-RST`.

Is it possible to implement such monitoring in Java? Using Netty library?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be achievable but one needs to use another low-level implementation of the TCP for java.

This library might help: https://github.com/mlaccetti/rocksaw/blob/master/src/main/java/com/savarese/rocksaw/net/RawSocket.java

An example of low-level sending `SYN` command:

https://github.com/dangan249/RawSocket/blob/master/ccs/neu/edu/andang/RawSocketClient.java#L181-L182

```
private final byte SYN_FLAG = (byte) 2;
private final byte ACK_FLAG = (byte) 16;

    ...
// send the SYN packet
sendMessage(null, this.getCurrentSeqNum(), this.getCurrentACKNum(), SYN_FLAG);
```

which boils down to just writing a proper packet into the socket:

```
TCPHeader header = new TCPHeader( this.sourcePort, this.destPort, sequenceNum ,
                ackNum, flags , AD_WINDOW_SIZE ) ;

TCPPacket packet = new TCPPacket( header );

...
this.rSock.write( this.destAddress, packet.toByteArray() ) ;
```

By doing that one can implement a needed sequence of operations including the wanted `SYN->SYNC-ACK<-RST`

Comment: Please help me with my question regarding Rawsock https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742594/how-to-implement-tcp-syn-scanning-with-java-code-fastest-way-to-scan-ports-with?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

@Andremoniy answer was refined to build a simple C binary doing half-open/embryonic check. The C binary binary has required RAW SOCKET Linux capability. It is executed from Java code using `Runtime.exec()`.
The advantage comparing to using `rocksaw` library is to avoid running the whole Java process with additional capabilities required for doing such check.